# Symfony 4, get .env parameter from a controller, is it possible and how?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4

From symfony 4, I want create a global parameter and get the value of this parameter from a controller.

This parameter is the path of an another app in the server. So, I thinked add the paramerter in the .env file. But how can I get the value of this parameter from a controller?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Did you try with:

```
$this->getParameter('your parameter');
```

Edit:

This may help you -> https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dotenv.html

Comment: Thank you for your answer :) I added the parameter foo in the .env file (foo=faa), I cleaared caches but I get an "InvalidArgumentException : The parameter 'foo' must be defined" in my controller :/

Comment: Edited my answer

Comment: Yes, I just saw that ! It's curious, I thinked that was a native method in Symfony !

Comment: I'm not very familiar with Symfony, there may be a native method in Symfony 4.

Answer (score 60):

For Symfony 5

in your `.env` file

```
APP_PARAM=paramvaluehere
```

in your `config/services.yaml`

```
parameters:
    app.paramname: '%env(APP_PARAM)%'
```

in your controller

```
$this->getParameter('app.paramname');
```

Comment: Works in 4.3 too.

Comment: You can simply do `$_SERVER['APP_PARAM']` with value only in .env file
https://symfony.com/doc/current/cloud/cookbooks/env.html#accessing-environment-variables

Comment: To be able to call `$this->getParameter('app.paramname')` make sure your controller `extends AbstractController`.

Comment: The `config/services.yaml` part is only required if your controller DOES NOT `extends AbstractController`.
https://symfony.com/doc/current/configuration.html#accessing-configuration-parameters

Answer (score 40):

If someone is stil looking for a quick fix but not much symfonish,

define your parameter in .env

```
MY_PARAM='my param value'
```

and then in controller call it

```
echo $_ENV['MY_PARAM'];
```

if you call the varaible in the controller you better define it in the `config/services.yaml` under `parameters` section and access it through `parameterBag` is much symfonish way.

Comment: I believe this is the default way to go from symfony 4.3+ ! Working in 5.2

Comment: With time you forget the basics. $_ENV should do the job for simple things like a functional test for example :) for more elaborated and Symfony way approach, use parameters.

Answer (score 13):

Before to use getParameter() you have to add this in services.yaml

```
parameters:
    your_parameter: '%env(your_parameter)%' # from .env file
```

Answer (score 8):

Yes it is. You have 03 steps configuration : 
Filstly - declare yours variables in env. 
Secondly - configure service file 
and finally - call your parameter in your controller :

_ In controllers extending from the **AbstractController**, use the getParameter() helper :

**YAML file config**

```
# config/services.yaml
parameters:
    kernel.project_dir: "%env(variable_name)%"
    app.admin_email: "%env(variable_name)%"
```

**In your controller,**

```
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;

class UserController extends AbstractController
{
    // ...

    public function index(): Response
    {
        $projectDir = $this->getParameter('kernel.project_dir');
        $adminEmail = $this->getParameter('app.admin_email');

        // ...
    }
}
```

_ If controllers not extending from **AbstractController**, inject the parameters as arguments of their constructors.

**YAML file config**

```
# config/services.yaml
parameters:
    app.contents_dir: "%env(variable_name)%"

services:
    App\Controllers\UserController :
        arguments:
            $contentsDir: '%app.contents_dir%'
```

**In your controller,**

```
class UserController 
{
    private $params;

    public function __construct(string $contentsDir)
    {
        $this->params = $contentsDir;
    }

    public function someMethod()
    {
        $parameterValue = $this->params;
        // ...
    }
}
```

_ Finally, if some controllers needs access to lots of parameters, instead of injecting each of them individually, you can inject all the application parameters at once by type-hinting any of its constructor arguments with the ContainerBagInterface:

**YAML file config**

```
# config/services.yaml
parameters:
    app.parameter_name: "%env(variable_name)%"
```

**In your service,**

```
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ParameterBag\ContainerBagInterface;

class UserController 
{
    private $params;

    public function __construct(ContainerBagInterface $params)
    {
        $this->params = $params;
    }

    public function someMethod()
    {
        $parameterValue = $this->params->get('app.parameter_name');
        // ...
    }
}
```

*source* [Accessing Configuration Parameters](https://symfony.com/doc/current/configuration.html#accessing-configuration-parameters)

Comment: apply corrections as suggested by @samuel-liew

Answer (score 6):

1. Add the variable in the config parameters :

```
    parameters:
        your_variable: '%env(YOUR_ENV_VARIABLE)%'
```

2. Fetch it from the controller

```
    $var = $this->getParameter('your_variable');
```

Answer (score 3):

In Symfony 4.4 this works fine:

```php
<?php
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

class SomeController extends AbstractController 
{

    public function someMethod(Request $request)
    {
        $parameterValue = $request->server->get('env_varname');
        // ...
    }
}
```

also in TWIG:

```
{{ app.request.server.get('env_varname') }}
```